# How to understand Redis memory usage?

Tags: redis

Running Redis 2.6.16 on CentOS 6.4

We like redis a lot. And we have been throwing more and more different stuff at it.

And now we have hit the maxmemory and are losing a few things we would rather not lose.

We would like to understand  what is in Redis. E.g. how many lists and how much space they all take, how many sets and how much space for all sets, that kind of thing. It would also be great to understand the profile of expirations (e.g. 100MB of stuff expires in the next 10 min, 200 more MB in 60 min, etc).

Is there a tool or approach to get to this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most of the things you want to know, Redis has very good documentation

[Memory Optimization](http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization)

There are some tools I can suggest to help you profile keys and memory used

1. [RDB - Redis Memory analyzer through dump](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools)
2. [Redis Sampler](https://github.com/antirez/redis-sampler) - Redis dataset composition
3. Few here https://github.com/antirez?tab=repositories

It is important to understand space and time complexity of different structures. How instagram wisely [used it](http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/12202313862/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value-pairs)

Comment: I use the RDB method, I make a copy of the dmp file, run rdb against it, with the memory option, then sort by memory used, desc, and voila! I have something to work with. Thanks!